# React Router works on link click but not on url entering

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a simple app:

```js
export default function App() {
  return (
     <div>
       <Routes>
         <Route element={<Layout />}>
           <Route index element={<Homepage />} />
           <Route path={homeUrl} element={<Homepage />} />
           <Route path={pageUrl} element={<Page1 />} />
         </Route>
       </Routes>
     </div>
  );
}
```

In my layout I have a navigation:

```html
<NavLink to={homeUrl}>Home</NavLink>
<NavLink to={pageUrl}>Page</NavLink>
```

The links work perfectly - I click on the navigation links, the URL is changing and the page is rendering.
**But** if I'm trying to enter the URLs directly (not with the links) or refreshing the page after clicking the links - I get 404.

Comment: See the [CRA deployment](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/) docs and find the relevant section matching how/where you are deploying your app and app the correct configuration. Or edit your question here to include the server details and we may be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide complete details but If I understand correctly, it can help you to solve your problem, if you have this problem on the server and when you open the homepage it works correctly and when open a subroute it goes to 404 page, add this to your .htaccess file

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```